# PowerShell : change local Administrator password

Tags: powershell

Logged-in to `$ComputerName` as local Administrator Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

This script :

```
$admin=[adsi]("WinNT://" + $ComputerName + "/administrator, user")
$admin.psbase.invoke("SetPassword", $Password)
$admin.psbase.CommitChanges()
```

run locally throws exception : `Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s):"The network path was not found"`

Comment: What's the value of $ComputerName?

Comment: `$ComputerName="WS08-SF-QA-1"`

Answer (score 4):

When I wanted to change local admin password accross all the servers in AD domain I simply used PS remoting which allows pushing even very basic commands from CMD to remote server.

I wrote a short script where I use powershell to obtain info from domain controller and based on certain conditions push command to the servers.

I find it as really easy and fast way how to change local admin password. The only requirement is to have WinRM enabled on all the servers.

The script is below here:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {net user administrator "Password01"} -ComputerName (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=test,OU=servers,DC=lab,DC=com" -Filter * | Select-Object -Expand Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have not tested this but i found

```
([adsi]“WinNT://<Local or Remote Computer Name>/<Username>”).SetPassword(“<Password>”)
```

http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-change-user-password-with-powershell.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried this code but with nearly identical result `The following exception occurred while retrieving member "SetPassword": "The network path was not found."`

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is really to change the password for the Administrator account (regardless of whether it's been renamed--it is not always named 'Administrator'), I recommend using a script like the one in this article:

[Windows IT Pro: Resetting the Local Administrator Password on Computers](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/resetting-local-administrator-password-computers)

The `Reset-LocalAdminPassword.ps1` script uses ADSI to connect to remote systems, so it is presumed that remote administration is permitted through the remote computer's firewall.

Since Penton was sold, all of the download links in my articles are broken, unfortunately. I have posted the script on GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/Bill-Stewart/d52bebe553fbfe01deebe745ce650bc0

Comment: When Informa bought Penton, they migrated the articles but broke all the download links. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a local computer, this works

```
$comp=hostname

("WinNT://" + $comp + "/<user_name_to_change_password_for>").SetPassword("<actualpasswordtext>")
```